# Can't open file a second time even though marked as Share Read using TFile

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe3

Given this code:

```
  FN := 'c:\temp\test_file.log';
  AFile := TFile.Open(FN, TFileMode.fmOpenOrCreate, TFileAccess.faReadWrite, TFileShare.fsRead);
  try
    with TFile.OpenRead(FN) do
    try

    finally
      Free;
    end;

  finally
    AFile.Free;
  end;
```

I get an error when trying to open at the TFile.OpenRead(FN) line:
[image]

using:

```
with TFile.Open('c:\temp\test_file.log', TFileMode.fmOpen, TFileAccess.faRead, TFileShare.fsRead) do
try

finally
  Free;
end;
```

also results in the same error.  As does:

```
  FS := TFileStream.Create('c:\temp\test_file.log', fmOpenRead or fmShareDenyWrite);
  try

  finally
    FS.Free;
  end;
```

However, I can happily open the file in Notepad say (as Readonly), or if I change the initial TFileShare.fsRead to TFileShare.fsNone, I can't open it as expected (in Notepad).

However, if I run two instances of this dummy app, first one opening with TFileShare.fsRead I can open it.  So am I unable to re-open a file twice in the same application?  Doesn't seem right.

If I open the file initially with:

```
  FS := TFileStream.Create('c:\temp\test_file.log', fmOpenReadWrite or fmShareDenyWrite);
  try

  finally
    FS.Free;
  end;
```

I can open it a second time with the above methods (where using fsRead).  What is confusing is stepping through the TFile.Open code, it ultimately executes the exact same code as the above TFileStream.Create.

Finaly note.  If I open using the top (first) way but assign it to a "global" variable, remove the internal TFile.OpenRead(FN) call, and then try to open the file through another button click say, the error persists.  This proves it's not related to the nested call.

Comment: Your problem lies in the fmOpenOrCreate flag. Do it in 3 steps: check if file exists, if not do fmCreate. close file, open now for readwrite and a second time readonly...

Comment: @whosrdaddy No, that's not it.

Comment: @whosrdaddy as David mentioned, that's not going to help.  TFile.Open checks for existence when passing in fmOpenOrCreate parameter as I was

Answer (score 13, accepted):

When you call

```
TFile.OpenRead(Path)
```

this is implemented by

```
TFileStream.Create(Path, fmOpenRead, 0)
```

which in turn leads to a call to

```
FileOpen(Path, fmOpenRead or 0)
```

which finally calls `CreateFile` passing `0` as `dwShareMode`. And the documentation for [`CreateFile`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/windows/desktop/aa363858.aspx) says that `dwShareMode` of `0` means:

> Prevents other processes from opening a file or device if they request delete, read, or write access.

In other words, `TFile.OpenRead(Path)` is trying to open the file with exclusive share mode. And that will clearly fail since the file is already open.

I think that `TFile.OpenRead(Path)` is using the wrong share mode. It should allow read access. However, even if that was the case it would not help you since your other handle has write access.

Solve the problem by avoiding `TFile.OpenRead`. Instead open it like this:

```
TFileStream.Create(Path, fmOpenRead or fmShareDenyNone)
```

You have to pass `fmShareDenyNone`. You are in no position to deny any form of sharing since you already opened it for both reading and writing.

---

There is a further problem which I had failed to grasp when I originally wrote this answer. It's true that `TFile.OpenRead()` always tries to gain exclusive access. But it's also true that your use of `TFile.Open()`, the very first call you make, can also result in exclusive access. Even though you specified `TFileShare.fsRead`.

The code in `TFile.Open()` that creates files stream reads like this:

```
if Exists(Path) then
  Result := TFileStream.Create(Path, LFileStrmAccess, LFileStrmShare)
else
  Result := TFileStream.Create(Path, fmCreate, LFileStrmShare);
```

Right off the bat this is a disaster. It's plain and simply wrong for file creation behaviour to be switched on file exists check. File creation needs to be an atomic operation. What if the file is created after `Exists` returns, but before the call to `CreateFile` that is made inside `TFileStream.Create`? But I guess the reason the code has been written like this is that there is no way to use `TFileStream.Create` and have `OPEN_ALWAYS` passed to `CreateFile`. And hence this horrid botch.

And it turns out that if the `fmCreate` option is chosen, because `Exists()` returns `False`, then your sharing options are ignored. That's because they are passed to the `Rights` parameter of `TFileStream.Create` instead of being combined with `fmCreate`. As the [documentation](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.Classes.TFileStream.Create) says, on Windows the `Rights` parameter is ignored.

So the correct code should be:

```
Result := TFileStream.Create(Path, fmCreate or LFileStrmShare);
```

And what about the other branch of the if? Surely that's wrong too. Since the valued passed to `Rights` is ignored, then surely the value of `LFileStrmShare` is ignored. Well, it turns out that the documentation lied. The code in `TFileStream.Create` reads:

```
constructor TFileStream.Create(const AFileName: string; Mode: Word; Rights: Cardinal);
var
  LShareMode: Word;
begin
  if (Mode and fmCreate = fmCreate) then
  begin
    LShareMode := Mode and $FF;
    if LShareMode = $FF then
      LShareMode := fmShareExclusive; // For compat in case $FFFF passed as Mode
    inherited Create(FileCreate(AFileName, LShareMode, Rights));
    if FHandle = INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE then
      raise EFCreateError.CreateResFmt(@SFCreateErrorEx, [ExpandFileName(AFileName), SysErrorMessage(GetLastError)]);
  end
  else
  begin
    inherited Create(FileOpen(AFileName, Mode or Rights));
    if FHandle = INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE then
      raise EFOpenError.CreateResFmt(@SFOpenErrorEx, [ExpandFileName(AFileName), SysErrorMessage(GetLastError)]);
  end;
  FFileName := AFileName;
end;
```

Look at the `else` branch where `Mode or Rights` is passed to `FileOpen`. That doesn't look very much like `Rights` is being ignored.

So all that explains why the sharing mode is set correctly in your call to `TFile.Open` if and only if the file already exists.

So, not only can you not use `TFile.OpenRead`, but `TFile.Open` is also out. Quit while you are ahead and give up on `TFile` altogether. I have no idea what happened with the QA at Embarcadero when `TFile` was introduced, but there was evidently a major failure. Combine that failure with the bizarre design flaws of `TFileStream.Create` and you have a veritable bug factory.

I submitted a QC report: [QC#115020](http://qc.embarcadero.com/wc/qcmain.aspx?d=115020). Quite interestingly the erroneous behaviour in `TFileStream.Create`, where `Rights` is used when it should not, is new to XE3. I believe it was an attempt to deal with the bogus code in `TFile.Open` which has already been reported as [QC#107005](http://qc.embarcadero.com/wc/qcmain.aspx?d=107005), which is incorrectly marked as Fixed. Sadly the attempt to fix `TFile.Open` leaves `TFile.Open` still broken, and in turn breaks `TFileStream.Create` which used to work!

Comment: Thanks.  Didn't think to delve into the Windows API (ultimately).  Thanks

Comment: @DavidHeffernan I don't agree in setting TFile.OpenRead as only guilty since TFile.Open allready will lock the file (except allready existing on XE3)

Comment: @bummi You are right. I will update. I'm afraid it's taken me until now to fully understand the point you've been making. I think your answer would benefit more words and less code!  ;-)

Comment: Thank's, you know I'm not the master of the words ... ;-)

Comment: @Jason I updated my answer. It turns out it was even more complex that I thought. There appear to be a large number of separate design flaws and outright bugs in the RTL that are all working against you. I think my answer pretty much covers it now.

Comment: Now you put the finger on the sore +1

Comment: @bummi Thanks. I think there's more. Stay tuned! And I'm going submit a big QC report too!

Comment: @David Heffernan - I did not downvote - I rarely, if ever downvote. I am going to stop answering because I do it late at night and don't have the wherewithall to read the questions correctly. I deleted my answer. You are a good cop.

Comment: @Mikey I'm sorry for accusing you. I should have known better. It turned out to be a fascinating question!

Comment: `inherited Create(FileCreate(AFileName, LShareMode, Rights));` - it seems that `Rights` is used despite `docwiki` claims in both THEN and ELSE branches, not only ELSE

Comment: @Arioch'The On Windows, `FileCreate` ignores the third parameter. It's only for setting permissions when creating a unix file.

Comment: @David Heffernan - 'It turned out to be a fascinating question!. OK - 'for those who find such things fascinating'. I am actually more interested in good design practices than chasing obscure Delphi bugs. My code tends to be very 'conservative' and discreet.

Comment: @Mikey False accusations based on no facts are not clever. I'm am not proud. Anyway, you seem like a jolly good sport! Do stick around.

Comment: @bummi Interesting thread on Emba forum: http://https://forums.embarcadero.com/thread.jspa?messageID=553235#553235

Answer (score 1):

with windows access rights are extracted from Mode in FileCreate and FileOpen which are called from TFileStream.Create.
[CreateFile](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa363858%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) is here called with ShareMode[(Mode and $F0) shr 4].

TFileMode.fmOpenOrCreate will call
TFileStream.Create(Path, fmCreate, LFileStrmShare); is the file is not existsing.

the behavoir can be show

```
function OpenReadShareALL(const Path: string): TFileStream;
begin
  If FileExists(Path) then
    begin
      try
        Result := TFileStream.Create(Path, fmOpenRead or fmShareDenyNone);
        // will work too at lest up to XE since rights are ignored in oder versions
        //Result := TFileStream.Create(Path, fmOpenRead or fmShareDenyNone,fmShareExclusive);
      except
        on E: EFileStreamError do
          raise EInOutError.Create(E.Message);
      end;
    end;
end;



var
  FN:String;
  AFile:TFileStream;
begin
  FN := 'c:\temp\test_file.log';
 // this will lock file at least until Delphi XE if file has to be created
 //AFile := TFile.Open(FN, TFileMode.fmOpenOrCreate, TFileAccess.faReadWrite, TFileShare.fsReadWrite);


 // the following will work
 if Fileexists(FN) then
    AFile := TFileStream.Create(fn,fmOpenRead or fmOpenWrite or fmShareDenyNone)
 else
    AFile := TFileStream.Create(fn,fmCreate  or fmShareDenyNone);      

 // won't work if file does not exists , and will not work with existing file up to at least Delphi XE (fixed in XE 3 , maybe XE 2 too)
 //  AFile := TFileStream.Create(fn,fmCreate or fmOpenReadWrite ,fmShareDenyNone);
  try
    with OpenReadShareAll(FN) do
    try
      Showmessage('Worked');
    finally
      Free;
    end;

  finally
    AFile.Free;
  end;
end;
```

In XE3 the ignoring of rights seems to be corrected for access modes other then fmCreate

```
inherited Create(FileOpen(AFileName, Mode or Rights));
```

Comment: Same behaviour whether or not it exists.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Yes, that's why I mentioned  FileCreate AND FileOpen

Comment: I'm afraid I cannot really understand your explanation. Sorry.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan my conclusion was that TFile.Open and TFile.OpenRead can not be used for the intended operation since there is no possibility to add fmShareDenyNone to the mode for FileCreate AND FileOpen. Since at least XE3 this is fixed for existing files, not for fmCreate.

Comment: Finally I have caught up. +1. I've tried to expand in my answer.

Comment: The `Rights` parameter is interesting. You are not meant to pass sharing mode in that parameter. It has nothing to do with sharing. It was added around Kylix time so that it could be passed to libc `open()`. It specifies Unix permissions. So the docs are correct when they say that `Rights` are ignored on Windows. They should be ignored. The documentation spells it out: `The Mode parameter consists of an open mode and (possibly) a share mode or'ed together.` So on Windows you should always use the two parameter version of `TFileStream.Create`. `TFile` class is totally bogus!

Comment: @DavidHeffernan I allways use the two parameter version, but found it interesting how strange the implemention for TFile is, also, because the behavior on newer versions has partially (and only partially) changed.

Comment: I think I've uncovered more. The change in TFileStream.Create, the introduction of Mode or Rights, is I believe an attempt by Emba to fix the problem with `TFile.Open`. Sadly the developer got it very badly wrong indeed! And now we have two bugs instead of just one!

Answer (score 1):

At least up to Delphi 2010 there is a similar issue. The base problem is that if the file is flagged as "create" some of the sharing flags are simply not taken into account.
You can read more about that on

http://cc.embarcadero.com/Item/21636

which should have a fix at least for the "old style" file creation where you "or"'ed toggether the flags.